# Swift Auto layout how to work with buttons

Tags: iphone, swift, layout

I've figured out auto layout for the most part to get my storyboards loading nicely on both iPhones and iPads.

The only issue I'm having is button and label text.

They don't seem to size properly according the screen size.
I've got the width and height of them to scale based on a multiplication factor.

How could I do that with the text size?

I've tried putting this in the viewDidLoad

```
 signup_btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    signup_btn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
    text_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    text_lbl.numberOfLines = 1
    login_btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    login_btn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
```

But that hasn't solved anything.

Comment: The `auto` tag is specific to C++ and does not apply here. I have removed the tag, in the future please use appropriate tags when create or editing a post.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main approaches to laying out a user interface.

You can programmatically lay out the user interface.

You can use autoresizing masks to automate some of the responses to external change

Or you can use Auto Layout.

Traditionally, apps laid out their user interface by programmatically setting the frame for each view in a view hierarchy. The frame defined the view’s origin, height, and width in the superview’s coordinate system.

To lay out your user interface, you had to calculate the size and position for every view in your view hierarchy. Then, if a change occurred, you had to recalculate the frame for all the effected views.

Other option is AutoResizingMask but you cannot use it for complex user interfaces.

Auto Layout represents an entirely new paradigm. Instead of thinking about a view’s frame, you think about its relationships.

I would highly recommend you to go through the following documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1

[This](https://github.com/Kadasiddha/dailPad/tree/master/dailpad) is an example for buttons without auto layout.

Also if the button and label position issue is occurring for only few screens then make different storyboard for these screen which doesn't have auto layout and different storyboard with auto layout.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I mean I understand auto layout only issue I have is getting the buttons text to adjust with the size of the button changing. The button size works fine but the text is stagnant no matter what I try.